# How to add a form partial HTMl with vue router?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a really long form .

I need to put it in a separate file or partials .
I don' t want to import Js script code, only HTML.

Tried this with no luck :

Profile.vue:

```js
<template>
        <div class="row">
        <form></form>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
import Form from "@/components/ProfileForm.vue";
export default {
    name: "Profile"
    components: {
        form:Form
    },
    data() {
        return {
            user: {
                _id:"",
                nom: "",
                prenom: "",
                phone: "",
                email: "",
                password: "",
                img: "",
                filenames: [],
                job: "",
                role: "user",
                age: ""
            }
        };
    }
}
```

ProfileForm.vue :

```js
<template>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row" v-if="!creationProcess">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>User Id </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>
                <input v-model="user._id" class="form-control" disabled />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  // AND SO ON
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "form"
};
</script>
```

Nothing appears, the form doesn't appear in my profile component, is there any way to do this in any other way ? Others components are working well, with the same kind of syntaxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it was pretty close to be working, i've made a few changes to get it working.

Also i've added the `user` prop, to send the `user` data into the actual form component.

Extra - Working Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-dream-79rsf

Profile.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Form :user="user"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Form from "./components/PartialForm";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Form
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        _id: "",
        nom: "",
        prenom: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        img: "",
        filenames: [],
        job: "",
        role: "user",
        age: ""
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

PartialForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row" v-if="!creationProcess">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>User Id</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>
          <input v-model="user._id" class="form-control" disabled>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>// AND SO ON
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "form",
  props: ["user"]
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying out this

Comment: It is working, but all of my parent functions aren't executables in the child component, how could I avoid copy pasting them inside of the child component ?

Comment: is there any way to avoid creating a new child component and just putting html in some files ?

Comment: You can use `this.$emit('func', value)` in a child method, and then put `@func="parentFunc($event)"` on the `Form` component

Comment: What do you mean by your latest comment?